# Why do Select Statement returns a row though the parameter in Where Clause didn't match any records?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in Microsoft Access:

```
PARAMETERS Username Text, Password Text;
//Value entered for Username = 'a'
//Value entered for Password = 'a'

SELECT ID, Username, Password, FormalName
FROM tblUsers
WHERE (Username = @Username) AND (Password = @Password)
```

I am expecting that this will not return a row because **there is no such Username 'a' and no such Password 'a'** but it did return a row:

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, there is clearly a user with that Username and Password in tblUsers. Can you provide more details as to why you think there is not one?

Comment: What does this return for you: `SELECT Username, Password FROM tblUsers WHERE ID = 1`?

Comment: It does return: Username 'wennie', Password '1234'

I only have one row in my tblUsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SQL Server syntax for the parameters in your Query, I would have expected it to look like this:

```
SELECT ID, Username, Password, FormalName
FROM tblUsers
WHERE (Username = [Username]) AND (Password = [Password])
```